# iOS app files that the user can download from the app

Tags: objective-c, download, filesystems, itunes

The idea is that i will create a file in the app and store some data in it.
I want for the end user to be able to download that file from the iOS device to his mac/pc.

Is this somehow possible? Where should i put the file for the user to be able to download it via itunes?

Comment: nevermind. this seems good: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/itunes-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app ... thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Here is good tutorial you can use:

[Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-create-email-attachment/)

It is important to know, that in iOS, when your user needs to create file, you do not need to care where to save it.

Another possibility for you might be to avoid saving data as file. For example, if your data is picture:

[UIImage send to email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656478/uiimage-send-to-email)

Comment: Thanks. There will be no email account on the devices. The files will be CSV.

Comment: I was saying about about the location because i know that the files stored under tmp for are not synced with iTunes. Maybe there is a folder where the user can get the data from within iTunes?